# increase the size of nodes in decision tree

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am using decision tree classifier and want to plot the tree using matplotlib

I am using this but nodes are small and not clear:

```
from sklearn import tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
tree.plot_tree(model_dt_smote,filled=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `axe` to `tree.plot_tree` with large `figsize` and set larger `fontsize` like below:

*(I can't run your code then I send an example)*

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import tree

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
iris = load_iris()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

fig, axe = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
tree.plot_tree(clf, ax = axe, fontsize=15)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I am still getting small nodes

Comment: @NitishSantpur do you write this : `fig, axe = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10)); tree.plot_tree(clf, ax = axe, fontsize=15)` you can change figsize and fontsize

Comment: Thankyou very much U ve made my work a lot simpler just a small doubt I am not getting the feature names                                                                                                                  model_dt_smote=DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini',random_state=100,max_depth=6,min_samples_leaf=8)                                                                                                           tree.plot_tree(model_dt_smote,
               filled = True,fontsize=10) can u just help me with this pls
I am getting something like the tree given above x[35] etc